# How can I see which sites have set the HSTS flag in my browser?

Tags: web-browser, hsts

My question is about Firefox and Chrome.

Is there a possibility to see which sites have set the HSTS flag in my browser?

Comment: For those on MacOS, the Firefox profile directories are under: `~/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/Profiles`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Chrome**:

- Open Chrome
- Type `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` in the address bar of chrome
- Query domain: if it appears as a result, it is HSTS-enabled

**Firefox**:

- Open file explorer
- Copy and paste the following path into the address bar of your file explorer

  - On **Windows**: `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\`
  - On **Linux**: `~/.mozilla/firefox`
  - On **Mac**: `~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles`
- Double click the folder you see (if you have multiple Firefox profiles, there will be multiple folders)
- Open `SiteSecurityServiceState.txt`. This textfile contains sites that have enabled HSTS.

Comment: So, there is no list for Chrome, just the queries?

Comment: Not as far as I know. You could take a look at the preloaded list: http://www.chromium.org/hsts

Comment: Yes, I know. But there are also sites which I visited which are not on the preload list.

Comment: I don't recall if it was there in 2015, but since at least my oldest mothballed system (XP, yes I said XP, with Firefox 52.9 from 2018) the in-use profile directory is available in Help / Troubleshooting Information

Comment: Firefox now uses a binary formatted file, `SiteSecurityServiceState.bin` so managing this with a text editor is not feasible anymore.

Answer (score 5):

There is a [Firefox plug-in called PinPatrol](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pinpatrol/) that lists all sites (preloaded and visited) known to have HSTS support.

> This is a Firefox extension that shows in a readable format, the state
> of HSTS and HPKP domains stored by the browser. Firefox does not have
> a native way to show these domains or this functionality documented.

Comment: Firefox now uses a binary formatted file, `SiteSecurityServiceState.bin` and as of this writing PinPatrol  does not support it.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the full Chrome HSTS list in the Chromium source code file [transport_security_state_static.json](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json)

Firefox [uses the same list](https://wiki.mozilla.org/SecurityEngineering/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_(HSTS)_Preload_List).

Comment: That's the preload list, and OP said in 2015 they don't want only preloads but also site dynamic settings.